# COUNT() rows value in an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join

I need to count the amount of games a player has played by counting the number of times his player ID appears on another table, here is the code I've been playing with:

```
SELECT players.playerID, players.fName, players.lName, matches.playerID, COUNT(matches.playerID) AS 'gamesPlayed'
        FROM players
        INNER JOIN matches
        ON matches.playerID = players.playerID
        WHERE players.playerID=matches.playerID
        ORDER BY gamesPlayed"
```

Currently there is 2 players having played 2 matches.

The current code returns 1 player having played 4 matches.

I am trying to get the COUNT(matches.playerID) to return only matches where the players.playerID = matches.playerID.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: At first place: your query lacks `GROUP BY`, at second - please check what argument `COUNT` accepts (in this query it's no different from `COUNT(*)`)

Comment: After including a group by the query now works, thank you zerkms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.playerID, p.fName, p.lName, COUNT(*) AS gamesPlayed
  FROM players p INNER JOIN matches m
    ON p.playerID = m.playerID
 GROUP BY p.playerID, p.fName, p.lName
 ORDER BY gamesPlayed
```

If you want even players who have played zero games, then:

```
SELECT p.playerID, p.fName, p.lName, COUNT(m.playerID) AS gamesPlayed
  FROM players p LEFT JOIN matches m
    ON p.playerID = m.playerID
 GROUP BY p.playerID, p.fName, p.lName
 ORDER BY gamesPlayed
```

The reason I use `COUNT(m.playerID)` instead of `COUNT(*)` in the above is because `COUNT(*)` will always be at least one in this instance, while `COUNT(m.playerID)` can be zero if the only matched value is `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for this, have decided to show even players with 0 games!

Answer (score 0):

At first place: your query lacks GROUP BY, at second - please check what argument COUNT accepts (in this query it's no different from COUNT(*)) –  zerkms